# Openpgpjs wont read key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openpgp, openpgp.js

I'm trying to encrypt text with OpenPGPJS in react application.

I have a function in react class:

```
const openpgp = require('openpgp');
...
class XYZ extends React.Component{
...
    async encrypt(text, targetKey){
        await openpgp.initWorker({ path: 'openpgp.worker.js' });
        var publicKey = (await openpgp.key.readArmored(targetKey.trim())).keys; 

        console.log(publicKey);
        
        const result = await openpgp.encrypt({
            message: openpgp.message.fromText(text),
            publicKeys: publicKey
        });
        console.log(result.data);
    }
...
const public_key = `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- .......`
const text = 'encrypt this'
this.encrypt(text, public_key);
```

for encryption.

I get an error message: `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Error encrypting message: No keys, passwords, or session key provided.`

I find out that `(await openpgp.key.readArmored(targetKey.trim())).keys;` return empty array, idk why.